# From classic multithreaded to java.nio asynchronous/non-blocking server

Tags: java

I'm the main developer of an online game. 
Players use a specific client software that connects to the game server with TCP/IP (TCP, not UDP)

At the moment, the architecture of the server is a classic multithreaded server with one thread per connection.
But in peak hours, when there are often 300 or 400 connected people, the server is getting more and more laggy.

I was wondering, if by switching to a java.nio.* asynchronous I/O model with few threads managing many connections, if the performances would be better.
Finding example codes on the web that cover the basics of such a server architecture is very easy. However, after hours of googling, I didn't find the answers to some more advanced questions:

1 - The protocol is text-based, not binary-based. The clients and the server exchanges lines of text encoded in UTF-8. A single line of text represents a single command, each lines are properly terminated by \n or \r\n.
For the classic multithreaded server, I have that kind of code :

```
public Connection (Socket sock) {
this.in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( sock.getInputStream(), "UTF-8" ));
this.out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
new Thread(this) .start();
}
```

And then in run, data are read line by line with readLine.

In the doc, I found an utilitiy class Channels that can create a Reader out of a SocketChannel. But it is said that the produced Reader wont work if the Channel is in non-blocking mode, what contradicts the fact that non-blocking mode is mandatory to use the highly performant channel selection API I'm willing to use. So, I suspect that it isn't the right solution for what I would like to do.
The first question is therefore the following: if I can't use that, how to efficiently and properly take care of breaking lines and converting native java strings from/to UTF-8 encoded data in the nio API, with buffers and channels?
Do I have to play with get/put or inside the wrapped byte array by hand? How to go from ByteBuffer to strings encoded in UTF-8 ? I admit to don't understand very well how to use classes in the charset package and how it works to do that.

2 - In the asynchronous/non-blocking I/O world, what about the handling of consecutive read/write that have by nature to be executed sequencially one after the other?
For example, the login procedure, which is typicly challenge-response-based: the server sends a question (a particular computation), the client sends the response, and then the server checks the response given by the client.
The answer is, I think, certainly not to make a single task to send to worker threads for the whole login process, as it is quite long, with the risk to freeze worker threads for too much time (Imagine that scenario: 10 pool threads, 10 players try to connect at the same time; tasks related to players already online are delayed until one thread is again ready).

3 - What happens if two different threads simultaneously call Channel.write(ByteBuffer) on the same Channel?
Do the client might receive mixed up lines ? For example if a thread sends "aaaaa" and another sends "bbbbb", could the client receive "aaabbbbbaa", or am I ensured that everyting is sent in a consist order? Am I allowed to modify the buffer used right after the call returned?
Or asked differently, do I need additional synchronization to avoid this sort of situation?
If I need additionnal synchronization, how to know when release locks and so on, upon write finishes?
I'm afraid that the answer isn't as simple as registering for OP_WRITE in the selector. By trying that, I noticed that I get the write-ready event all the time and always for all clients, exiting Selector.select early mostly for nothing, since there are only 3 or 4 messages to send pers second per client, while the selection loop is performed hundreds of times per second. So, potentially, active wait in perspective, what is very bad.

4 - Can multiple threads call Selector.select on the same selector simultaneously without any concurrency problems such as missing an event, scheduling it twice, etc?

5 - In fact, is nio as good as it is said to be ? Would it be interesting to stay to classic multithreaded model, but unstead of creating a thread per connection, use fewer threads and loop over the connections to look for data availability using InputStream.isAvailable ? Is that idea stupid and/or inefficient?

Comment: For some example code take a look at the source for Netty: https://github.com/netty/netty it is a really good library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes. I think that you need to write your own nonblocking readLine method. Note also that a nonblocking read may be signaled when there are several lines in the buffer, or when there is an incomplete line:

Example: (first read)

```
 USER foo
 PASS
```

(second read)

```
 bar
```

You will need to store (see 2) the data that was not consumed, until enough information is ready to process it.

```
 //channel was select for OP_READ
 read data from channel 
 prepend data from previous read
 split complete lines
 save incomplete line
 execute commands
```

2) You will need to keep the state of each client.

```
    Map<SocketChannel,State> clients = new HashMap<SocketChannel,State>();
```

when a channel is connected, `put` a fresh state into the map

```
    clients.put(channel,new State());
```

Or store the current state as [the attached object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html#attach%28java.lang.Object%29) of the `SelectionKey`.

Then, when executing each command, update the state. You may write it as a monolithic method, or do something more fancy such as polymorphic implementations of `State`, where each state knows how to deal with some commands (e.g. `LoginState` expects USER and PASS, then you change the state into a new `AuthorizedState`).

3) I don't recall using NIO with many asynchronous writers per channel, but the documentation says it is thread safe (I won't elaborate, since I have no proof of this). About OP_WRITE, note that it signals when the write buffer is **not full**. In other words, as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053924/java-nio-server): OP_WRITE is almost always ready, i.e. except when the socket send buffer is full, so you will just cause your `Selector.select()` method to spin mindlessly.

4) Yes. `Selector.select()` performs a [blocking selection operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#select%28%29).

5) I think that the most difficult part is switching from a thread-per-client architecture, to a different design where reads and writes are decoupled from processing. Once you have done that, it is easier to work with channels than working your own way with blocking streams.

Comment: Could you add some precisions ? Q1: do I need to manually play with get/put in the buffer, or manually search for \n in the wrapped byte array, to split up the lines, or is there any better way  ? Q2: could I use the user object of a SelectionKey to store that state information ? +I will add an additionnal subquestion to question 1 to be more precise. Thank for your answers so far.