# is it necessary to store incoming messages in java UDP server implementation?

Tags: java, nio

Good day everybody!

I'm developing simple java UDP server based on java NIO. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348035/from-classic-multithreaded-to-java-nio-asynchronous-non-blocking-server) I read that I have to store all incoming messages in some buffer and somehow recognize line breaks. But is it necessary for me to store previous states if incoming messages size always <= buffer size? I mean my ByteBuffer is large enough to store any incoming messages. Are there some cases when it's better to ensure myself from handling some messages like monolit whereas they are just part of some big message? I just don't want to do overhead job and want to precise is  allocating large enough buffer dangerous strategy or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question that you quoted is about TCP channels, which are different from the UDP channels that you are using.

TCP is *byte oriented* (that is, there are no "messages" in the TCP layer; TCP is a single stream of bytes, and splitting the stream in "messages" is a concern of the application). The application has to process the byte-stream and extract the messages. A host may write some bytes into a TCP channel, then it writes more bytes; the other host cannot tell if they were written in two (or more) different operations, or in a single one. The other host does only read the bytes, in the same order that they were sent.

UDP, on the other hand, is *datagram oriented*: you send some bytes (a datagram) from one host, and the other host will receive that datagram. Datagrams are neither merged nor splitted (but they may be lost). [DatagramChannel.read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html#read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) will return exactly one datagram. If every message fits in an UDP datagram, then you don't need to keep a buffer.

However, if you have messages that are sent in several UDP datagrams, you will need a buffer in order to reconstruct the original message. You will also need to take care for message order (since UDP datagrams may be reordered by the network) and missing datagrams (because UDP is [not reliable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_%28computer_networking%29))

Comment: Could you precise is sending some short message is equivalent to  sending 1 Datagram? Are the possibility that client machine will divide my message into several datagrams even if this message is short?

Comment: A call to `DatagramChannel.send` sends **only a single datagram**, and it will not be divided by the client machine.

Comment: Actually I don't use DatagramChannel.send on the client side - it is some device configured to sending messages to some IP adress by UDP protocol. I don't know how it sends messages to me internally. It seems the only way to test it is analyzing logs from this device)